# cob1904510_0.c:(.text+0x3b): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'

Tags: c, linux, 32bit-64bit, gnucobol, icx

Getting this error during linking. In this project, we have GnuCOBOL and C codes, so all objects are created using respective compilers but all linking are done using intel's icx compiler only. While creating below binary I facing issues. We are migrating from HP-UX 32 bits to LINUX 64 bits.

```
/opt/intel/bin/icx "-Wl,-copy-dt-needed-entries" -o /home/cellusers/abhyudga/proj/clg946/bin/executeable executable_Main.o /home/proj/lib/libcbl.a /home/proj/lib/libcac.a /home/proj/lib/libclcar.a /home/proj/lib/libschapi.a /home/proj/lib/libopign.a /home/proj/lib/libopi.a /home/proj/lib/libclcgn.a /home/proj/lib/libcdl.a /home/proj/lib/libclcinftl.a /home/proj/lib/libclcinfgn.a   -L/home/proj/lib -L/home/proj/lib  -L/home/proj/clb946/lib  -L/home/proj/clg946/cla946/lib -L/usr/local/lib/hpux32 -L/oracle/oravl01/bea/tuxedo12.2.2.0.0/lib  -L/usr/local/gnucobol-3.1.2/lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib64  -lclcbl -lclcrt -lclcmtrt -lclcar -lclcbl -lclccsm -lclcar -lcellch -lclcnm -lclcltr -lclcar -lclcint -lclcbl -lclccbf -lclcup -lclcbl -lclccsm -lclcar -lclcrms -lclcgn -lclcsc -lclcrt -lclcbl -lclcint -lclcdl -lclcgn -lclcdl -lclcac -lclcopign -lclcinfgn -lclcopi -L/ORACLE_HOME/app/oracle/product/19.3/lib  -lcob /opt/intel/lib/libirc.so -lrt -lxml2 -lxml2  /ORACLE_HOME/app/oracle/product/19.3/precomp/lib/cobsqlintf.o -lclntsh /ORACLE_HOME/app/oracle/product/19.3/lib/libsql19.a
/home/proj/lib/libclcgn.a(ShortNames.o): In function `MakeShortName':
/home/bb/clcgn/gn/src/ShortNames.c:289: warning: the use of `tempnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
/home/proj/lib/libcbl.a(bltxcredit.o): In function `bltxcredit':
cob237325_0.c:(.text+0x40): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
cob237325_0.c:(.text+0x48): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
/home/proj/clg946/lib/libcbl.a(bltxcredit.o): In function `bltxcredit_':
cob237325_0.c:(.text+0x10f): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
cob237325_0.c:(.text+0x129): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
cob237325_0.c:(.text+0x15e): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
cob237325_0.c:(.text+0x197): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
cob237325_0.c:(.text+0x1a6): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
cob237325_0.c:(.text+0x1fd): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
cob237325_0.c:(.text+0x20b): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
cob237325_0.c:(.text+0x219): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against `.bss'
cob237325_0.c:(.text+0x227): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
/usr/bin/ld: failed to convert GOTPCREL relocation; relink with --no-relax
icx: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
gmake: *** [/home/bb/cbl/rr/src/make.bin:21: executable] Error 1
```

Comment: I _guess_ you want to use the Intel toolset and also compile your C sources with that, right?
Do you also build GnuCOBOL 3.2 on that machine using the Intel toolset? If not I'd _highly_ suggest to do so.

Comment: No, the object from which I am getting this issue is also gnuCOBOL, so I just want to create a binary using icx, also I have compiled all the codes using -mcmodel=medium argument.

Comment: I'd suggest to build GnuCOBOL 3.2 using the intel toolset - in this case all objects are generated by that. If you need help with that https://sourceforge.net/p/gnucobol/discussion/help/ seems to be the most appropriate place.

Comment: You mean compiling all the gnuCOBOL codes using icx compiler?

Comment: If you install GnuCOBOL 3.2 from source, then you can pass `CC=icx` and GnuCOBOL itself and all modules it creates will use this compiler.

Comment: Any news about recreating your GnuCOBOL environment to use the C compiler you otherwise use? (How) did that make a difference to the issue you've posted?

Comment: I declared **COB_CC = icx** and recompiled and now "relocation truncated to fit" issue was resolved but still I am getting "/usr/bin/ld: failed to convert GOTPCREL relocation; relink with --no-relax" error

Comment: I tried linking using **-mno-relax** option still didn't work

Comment: The question was about rebuilding GnuCOBOL and tell GnuCOBOL to use icx...

Comment: The basic question is related to the linking issues that I have been facing while linking GnuCOBOL codes, using icx to compile GnuCOBOL is one solution and it resolved the problem partially, that's why I am requesting for other suggestions as well. Can you please help with it?

Comment: Also want to point out that we also migrated from MicroFocus COBOL to GnuCOBOL.

Comment: If your problem is "partially" resolved then better create a new question with your scenario, setup and problem.

For discussions and back and forth sourceforge.net/p/gnucobol/discussion/help seems to be the most appropriate place.

Comment: As you have mentioned the issue was partially resolved, could you please confirm whether you still face any issues related to Intel oneAPI components, So that we can investigate the case? If yes, please provide us with the code, steps, and error you are facing.

Comment: @SeshaP-Intel, the issue is resolved now, thanks!